# Lua _G metatable not working

Tags: lua, metatable

I am trying to control the interactive environment. Here is my try:

```
home: lua
Lua 5.0.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2006 Tecgraf, PUC-Rio
> for n in pairs(_G) do io.write(n) end
stringxpcallLUA_PATHtostringgcinfoloadlibosunpackrequiregetfenvsetmetatablenext_TRACEBACKasserttonumberiorawequalcollectgarbagegetmetatable_LOADEDrawsetmathLUA_CPATHpcalldebug__powtypetablecoroutineprint_Gnewproxyrawgetloadstring_VERSIONdofilesetfenvpairsipairserrorloadfile> 
> G=_G
> _G={}
> setmetatable(_G,{__index=G,__newindex=function() print("nope") end})
> for n in pairs(_G) do io.write(n) end
> x=3
>
```

I expect the see "nope" after the command "x=3". However, it goes through. Isn't _G empty, and any access/update of _G will go through the defined meta methods?

Comment: btw, why are you using lua 5.0? thats a decade old! Use lua 5.3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Lua 5.0 manual:

> **_G**
>
> A global variable (not a function) that holds the global environment (that is, `_G._G = _G`). Lua itself does not use this
>   variable; changing its value does not affect any environment. (Use
>   `setfenv` to change environments.)

More specifically, in the interactive Lua interpreter you need `setfenv( 0, new_global_env )` to change the environment of the currently running thread to `new_global_env`.

Example:

```
Lua 5.0.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2006 Tecgraf, PUC-Rio
> do
>> local rawget, print, _G = rawget, print, _G
>> local new_global_env = setmetatable( { tostring = tostring }, {
>>   __index = function( t, k )
>>     print( "get", k )
>>     return rawget( _G, k )
>>   end
>> } )
>> setfenv( 0, new_global_env )
>> end
> print( "hello" )
get print
hello
>
```

(The upvalues of `rawget`, `print`, and `_G`, and the new `tostring` global are necessary to avoid infinite recursion.)

Comment: setfenv(0,...) solves the problem! I don't quite get the infinite recursion though. A bit more elaboration?

Comment: @user3015347: The `__index` function is called whenever Lua tries to look up a global variable. While executing `__index` the global `print` function is called. Since the global environment does not contain a `print` entry, the `__index` function is called again (and again ...). Same for `rawget` and `_G` which are also used in the `__index` function. The global `tostring` is called internally by the `print` function to convert its arguments to strings for output. Upvalues can't be used in this case because we don't have access to `print`'s definition.

Comment: thanks, siffiejoe, I think I followed your explain. Now I start to worry what functions are used in rawget(), if it needs functions other than print, _G, tostring in its definition, infinite recursion will happen again?

Comment: It's not as bad as you think. Most C functions don't access globals -- `print` is pretty much *the* exception in Lua's standard library. And Lua functions are different anyway, and save the value of the global environment that the currently running thread had when the function was created.